# Google Sheets Date and Time Objects Imported to R

Tags: r, google-docs-api, date-conversion

I used the RGoogleDocs package by OmegaHat to import my Google Sheets spreadsheet to R.
Some of it comprises of Date data, Time data and date/time data.

Upon importing to R, RGoogleDocs converts dates and times to decimal numbers presumably as the number of seconds from starting reference 1900-1-1 (or 1899-12-30).

This is not a problem for dates as I can simply use `as.Date()` to convert it.
However, time data is a huge nuisance.

I know that I can use the `as.POSIXct()` or `as.POSIXlt()` however this does not accurately convert the decimal numbers back to dates and times.

```
Observe:

Timestamp:
2/10/2014 19:22:40; 2/10/2014 19:52:07; 2/10/2014 20:14:47;

2/10/2014 21:08:03; 2/11/2014 11:05:39; 2/11/2014 12:21:40;

2/11/2014 12:44:33;  2/11/2014 16:08:54; 2/11/2014 16:31:44;

2/12/2014 10:54:31; 2/12/2014 11:38:15; 2/12/2014 11:56:18;

2/12/2014 12:31:53; 2/12/2014 14:42:46; 2/12/2014 15:03:36;

2/13/2014 14:38:17; 2/13/2014 15:08:45; 2/13/2014 16:39:27;

2/13/2014 17:18:45; 2/13/2014 19:14:23; 2/19/2014 15:01:16;

2/19/2014 15:05:43;
```

RGoogleDocs' Imported Version:

```
> mydata$"Timestamp"
 [1] 41680.81 41680.83 41680.84 41680.88 41681.46 41681.52 41681.53 41681.67
 [9] 41681.69 41682.45 41682.48 41682.50 41682.52 41682.61 41682.63 41683.61
[17] 41683.63 41683.69 41683.72 41683.80 41689.63 41689.63
```

After conversion:

```
    as.POSIXct(mydata$"Timestamp"*86400, origin = "1899-12-30")
 [1] "2014-02-11 00:22:40 PKT" "2014-02-11 00:52:07 PKT" "2014-02-11 01:14:47 PKT"
 [4] "2014-02-11 02:08:02 PKT" "2014-02-11 16:05:39 PKT" "2014-02-11 17:21:40 PKT"
 [7] "2014-02-11 17:44:33 PKT" "2014-02-11 21:08:54 PKT" "2014-02-11 21:31:44 PKT"
[10] "2014-02-12 15:54:31 PKT" "2014-02-12 16:38:15 PKT" "2014-02-12 16:56:18 PKT"
[13] "2014-02-12 17:31:53 PKT" "2014-02-12 19:42:45 PKT" "2014-02-12 20:03:36 PKT"
[16] "2014-02-13 19:38:17 PKT" "2014-02-13 20:08:45 PKT" "2014-02-13 21:39:27 PKT"
[19] "2014-02-13 22:18:45 PKT" "2014-02-14 00:14:22 PKT" "2014-02-19 20:01:16 PKT"
[22] "2014-02-19 20:05:42 PKT"
```

Not only are the times inaccurate, the error progressively increases down the list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a public version of your google spreadsheet (even just the timestamp column)?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqIRsZWcpw-gdEJZV01UVGNSWkxqSlI1VkRrN2NOdXc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for posting the link. I made a copy (so you can un-share it if you want now :-). Despite the spreadsheet properties being GMT-8, it looks like `RGoogleDocs` is giving you the numeric bit in GMT (UTC). I'm not posting all the setup code for `RGoogleDocs` but I assume you did something like the following:

```
docs <- getDocs(sheets.con)
ts <- getWorksheets(docs$rrr, sheets.con)
dat <- sheetAsMatrix(ts$`Form Responses`, header = TRUE, as.data.frame = TRUE, trim = TRUE)
```

`RGoogleDocs` does, indeed, send back the number of days value vs the timestamp string (despite the CSV export using the string version):

```
dat$Timestamp
##  [1] 41689.63 41683.72 41680.88 41680.81 41683.69 41681.67 41681.69 41682.45 41682.48 41682.50 41683.80
## [12] 41689.63 41680.83 41681.52 41681.46 41680.84 41682.52 41682.61 41683.61 41683.63 41681.53 41682.63
```

But, I'm not seeing the conversion errors (perhaps a few seconds) that you are:

```
as.POSIXct(dat$Timestamp*86400, origin="1899-12-30 00:00:00", tz="GMT")
##  [1] "2014-02-19 15:05:42 GMT" "2014-02-13 17:18:45 GMT" "2014-02-10 21:08:03 GMT"
##  [4] "2014-02-10 19:22:39 GMT" "2014-02-13 16:39:27 GMT" "2014-02-11 16:08:53 GMT"
##  [7] "2014-02-11 16:31:44 GMT" "2014-02-12 10:54:31 GMT" "2014-02-12 11:38:14 GMT"
## [10] "2014-02-12 11:56:18 GMT" "2014-02-13 19:14:23 GMT" "2014-02-19 15:01:15 GMT"
## [13] "2014-02-10 19:52:07 GMT" "2014-02-11 12:21:40 GMT" "2014-02-11 11:05:38 GMT"
## [16] "2014-02-10 20:14:46 GMT" "2014-02-12 12:31:52 GMT" "2014-02-12 14:42:45 GMT"
## [19] "2014-02-13 14:38:17 GMT" "2014-02-13 15:08:45 GMT" "2014-02-11 12:44:33 GMT"
## [22] "2014-02-12 15:03:36 GMT"
```

(Pasting the CSV export from Google Docs vs use a screen cap)

```
Timestamp,DOA,DOD,Length of Stay,Time of Event,Date of Event,Presentation Time,Presentation Date,Time to Presentation
2/19/2014 15:05:43,9/6/2010,9/10/2010,4,,,0:30:00,9/6/2010,
2/13/2014 17:18:45,12/28/2009,1/1/2010,4,16:13:00,,20:59:00,12/28/2009,
2/10/2014 21:08:03,12/28/2009,1/2/2010,5,16:13:00,12/28/2009,17:51:00,12/28/2009,
2/10/2014 19:22:40,12/28/2009,1/1/2010,4,16:00:00,12/28/2009,22:00:00,12/28/2009,
2/13/2014 16:39:27,3/22/2013,3/29/2013,7,,,4:46:00,3/22/2013,
2/11/2014 16:08:54,2/21/2013,4/3/2013,41,18:00:00,2/16/2013,2:49:00,2/21/2013,
2/11/2014 16:31:44,2/21/2013,2/27/2013,6,18:00:00,,5:35:00,2/21/2013,
2/12/2014 10:54:31,2/21/2013,3/5/2013,12,,,5:35:00,2/21/2013,
2/12/2014 11:38:15,2/21/2013,3/12/2013,19,18:00:00,2/20/2013,3:14:00,2/21/2013,
2/12/2014 11:56:18,2/21/2013,2/27/2013,6,,,3:16:00,2/21/2013,
2/13/2014 19:14:23,3/4/2013,3/21/2013,17,19:00:00,,2:05:00,3/4/2013,
2/19/2014 15:01:16,3/3/2013,3/19/2013,16,22:00:00,,0:00:00,3/4/2013,
2/10/2014 19:52:07,3/3/2013,3/5/2013,2,,3/3/2013,22:16:00,3/3/2013,
2/11/2014 12:21:40,4/24/2013,5/28/2013,34,19:00:00,4/23/2013,23:30:00,4/24/2013,
2/11/2014 11:05:39,3/5/2013,3/13/2013,8,21:25:00,3/3/2013,4:17:00,3/5/2013,
2/10/2014 20:14:47,5/5/2013,6/3/2013,29,21:45:00,5/5/2013,0:45:00,5/5/2013,
2/12/2014 12:31:53,11/23/2013,11/29/2013,6,23:35:00,11/23/2013,1:01:00,11/23/2013,
2/12/2014 14:42:46,11/26/2013,12/11/2013,15,9:20:00,,22:18:00,11/26/2013,
2/13/2014 14:38:17,12/12/2013,12/24/2013,12,,,21:56:00,12/11/2013,
2/13/2014 15:08:45,3/4/2013,3/14/2013,10,,3/3/2013,2:30:00,3/4/2013,
2/11/2014 12:44:33,8/9/2013,8/20/2013,11,,8/8/2013,10:43:00,8/9/2013,
2/12/2014 15:03:36,9/28/2013,9/30/2013,2,,,12:14:00,9/28/2013,
```

Can you verify the time zone settings both for your Google Drive defaults and the spreadsheet itself? That might be the issue.

Comment: Both my machine and the spreadsheet are set to the same time zone PKT.
However, I added `tz = "GMT"` to the line, just like you did and it worked.  Perhaps RGoogleDocs eliminates the interval difference and resets to UTC during import.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Wait, hang on.... I tried doing calculations with with rest of time data in the sheet and they turn out fine without adding `tz = "GMT"`. Then I realized that `Timestamp` was an automated generation by Google. This spreadsheet was linked to a form and I wanted to keep track of my research progress so I built in an automatic time stamp to pace data collection. THAT timestamp was posted as per UTC. The rest of the data follows PKT religiously.
So I accidentally ended up with two different time zones in the same data set.

Nonetheless, thank you @hrbrmstr for making me realize I need to account for timezones!
I'll contact you if I have problems with daylight savings.

Comment: Ah. Yes. That makes sense. There's been a love/hate relationship with `=NOW()` by Google Docs (Drive) users. It feels less predictable then it ought to be. It is *supposed to* use the local spreadsheet TZ setting, but I've seen product forum posts (and experienced it myself) when it doesn't. If only we had all switched to Swatch [Internet Time](http://www.swatch.com/zz_en/internettime/) when we had the chance :-)